# Antenna Theory and Electron Paramagnetic Resonance

Tags: antenna, electron

Hi I am trying to understand why and how Antenna Theory works as it does.

I can only link Antenna Theory to Electron Paramagnetic Resonance @ 2.8Ghz but I do not know how I can link the resonant movement of Electrons in the Antenna.

Can anyone give me more information on where I may look to try to answer my questions?

Comment: Don't think about electrons, Think about Impedance changes vs length as it gets shorter towards a wavelength and fractions like 1/2, 1/4 of lambda.  An E field in uV/mm is coupled with losses depending on aperture size of antenna and how it matches the impedance on both sides, free space and electrical.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/continuous-wave-electron-paramagnetic-resonance